# Razor View - change variable value based on an input

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to dynamically change the value of a Razor View variable (in my particular case, `field`) depending on an HTML element that is not binded with `@model`. In other words, if I select an item from the `select` dropdown, is there a way I can save that value into my `var field`?

```cs
@model MyClass

@{
    int field = 5; // some dummy value
}

<select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

@Html.DoStuff(field)
```

Comment: 1. "if I select an item from the select dropdown, is there a way ...":  You have to use `javascript`(or `Blazor`) to do that.  Note `Razor` only **runs on server side** . It has no knowledge when you click something within browser. 2. As a quick fix:  replace the `@Html.DoStuff(field)` with a plain placeholder `<div id='placeholder'></div>`, And  add an `onchange` event for your `<select id="select">` such that it sends an ajax request and gets a partial view from server side, finally replace the child content of `<div id='placeholder'></div>`